# How to stream MS Word document to browser via save button?

Tags: java, sharepoint, ms-word, webdav

Are there any technologies/frameworks available that will allow a user to download a MS Word document from the browser, then stream the document back to the browser with the save button? This would be similar to MS SharePoint. When a document is opened (via IE) from SharePoint, you can save with CTRL+S and close the document, and the next time it is opened the changes are visible. Is this possible in a custom app?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what WebDAV is for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

> Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV) is an extension of
>   the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) that facilitates collaboration
>   between users in editing and managing documents and files stored on
>   World Wide Web servers. A working group of the Internet Engineering
>   Task Force (IETF) defined WebDAV in RFC 4918.
>
> The WebDAV protocol makes the Web a readable and writable medium.[1]
>   It provides a framework for users to create, change and move documents
>   on a server; typically a web server or web share.

More details on specifics here: http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only

Comment: Thanks, I will educate myself on WebDAV. It's a Java app running on Glassfish v2.1. Haven't found any good looking open source WebDAV tools, currently looking at [this.](http://www.webdavsystem.com/javaserver)